# gcutil to add new user to project

Tags: ssh, cygwin, google-compute-engine, gcutil

Hi i have a project in my google cloud engine and i'm having ubunutu laptop i have set gcutil
in my laptop .
 I need another user to login to same project he is using windows machine i have set up   **gcutill**  via cygwin 
But the problem is i have create another user to compute engine .
Please guide me to set the second user to login into the same instance of project and both should have equal privileges on editing the project.
 Please ask me if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new user to your project, visit https://cloud.google.com/console. Click on `Permissions` in the left-hand column. This page allows you to add additional users to your project. Click the `Add User` button, enter their email address (it should be a Google account) and to give them exactly the same permissions as the person who created the project, choose `Owner` for the permissions.

Now that user can authenticate `gcutil` using their account.